# Show that coefficients of $\eta(z)^2 \eta(11z)^2$ are multiplicative

Tags: modular-forms, l-functions, euler-product

Can someone help me find the Euler product associated to this [newform](http://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/11/2/1/a/)? I have a product of [eta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) functions:

$$ \eta(z)^2 \eta(11z)^2 = q \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^2 (1 - q^{11n})^2  = q - 2q^2 - q^3 + 2q^4 + q^5 + 2 q^6 - 2 q^7 - 2q^9 + \text{O}(q^{10})$$

is a modular form of weight $2$ over $\Gamma_0(11)$.  What is a presentation of that group? What are the generators there?  I think 
$$ \Gamma_0(11) = \langle z \mapsto z + 11, z \mapsto - \frac{1}{z} \rangle $$
so these are like continued fractions all of whose digits are multiples of 11?   In any case, I did verify multiplicative in some cases:
$$ a_9 \times a_5 = (-2) \times (+1) = -2 = a_{45} $$
However, in certain other cases, in particular prime powers, the coefficients were not multiplicative:
$$ \quad \quad \; a_2 \times a_2 \times a_2 = (-2)\times (-2)\times (-2) = -8 \neq 0 = a_8 $$
All the number theory books prove these theorems abstractly, but I am failing to verify them for specific cases. 
$$ L(f,s) = 1^s -2 \times 2^s - 1 \times 3^s + 2 \times 4^s + 1 \times 5^s + 2 \times 6^s  + \dots = \left( 1 - \frac{a_{11}}{11^s} \right)^{-1} \prod_{p \neq 11} \left( 1 - \frac{a_p}{p^s} \right)^{-1} $$
 I would like to verify the Euler product for the L-function.

Comment: Multiplicativity in this game always boils down to proving it's a Hecke eigenform. In this case, this will follow from the space of weight 2 forms for $\Gamma_0(11)$ being one-dimensional. I should add that the L-function in this case will be that associated to the elliptic curve of conductor 11.

Comment: @LordShark did you search on http://www.lmfdb.org/ or what ?

Comment: my link is lmfdb

Comment: You are confusing multiplicative : $a_{nm} = a_n a_m$ when $gcd(n,m)=1$ with completely multiplicative $a_{nm} = a_n a_m$ for every $n,m$

Comment: In the case of Hecke eigenforms (the only modular forms having multiplicative coefficients, once normalized) there is a relation more constrained than just being multiplicative : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecke_operator#Explicit_formula

Comment: In general, we need to find the dimension of $S_2(\Gamma_0(11))$ on lmfdb, show that your function $f(\tau)$ belongs to it, find a basis of Hecke eigenforms, and decompose $f(\tau)$ in this basis (solving a linear equation for the first few coefficients). There it is : http://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/11/2/1/ so $\dim(S_2(\Gamma_0(11))) = 1$ and it makes all this trivial

Comment: @user1952009 are my generators for $\Gamma_0(11)$ correct?

Comment: No, $\Gamma_0(N)$ contains $z \mapsto z+1$ and doesn't contain $z \mapsto -1/z$. In general there are more than two generators for congruence subgroups

Comment: @user1952009 keep in mind this is Math.SE I am not an expert in modular forms, and would give you the check mark if you give a more thorough response.

Comment: I'm not an expert neither, but I read seriously the 1st half of [Diamond & Shurman](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Fred%20Diamond%20Jerry%20Shurman%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Modular%20Forms.pdf)